# insert to database utf-8 encoding

Tags: java, php, mysql

I get some data in java from http and then I want insert all data in one query to my database using java and php script but i have error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual >that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the >right syntax to use near '??okietka', '247335'), at line 1

What is interesting when i copy text from http and add manualy it works, but when i get data from url and then my program put this data i have this error. 
I think it is a coding problem. 
my insert php file :

```
   <?php
require "connection.php";
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');

$table_name = $_POST["table_name"];
$rows_name = $_POST["rows_name"];


$values = $_POST["values"];
mysqli_set_charset($connection,'utf8');

$mysql_query = "insert ignore into $table_name $rows_name values $values";
if(mysqli_query($connection,$mysql_query) == TRUE){
    echo "Insert Succesful" ;
}
else{
    echo "Error: " . $mysql_query . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Other data from http I successfully inserted.

**Edit:** I think i solved this problem adding this to php:

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
mysqli_set_charset($connection,'utf8');
```

Comment: Oh my. OT: If you are creating a new script, use mysqli functions (mysql is depreciated), and look into prepared statements (which do not work with dynamic table and column names btw), because you are wide open for some serious sql injection attacks with that way you have there.

Comment: There must be some escaping issue, show us the data?

Comment: @Chiru i only get values from url, table_name and rows_name i send from java and i put it manually there. Generally i edited my post and i think now it works

Comment: Try adding chartset in connection string something like this dbname=xxzzz;host=xxxzzz;charset=utf8